# jquery mobile logging in and accessing/rejecting page

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, authentication, jquery-mobile

I know this site isn't asking for people to work on a specific code, but I'm having a real hard time looking for examples/tutorial on jquery mobile login. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, but I'm trying to get a user to login based on mysql database (if user is in my database), but I'm trying to figure out what to write up when user logs in? How do i set up so it will redirect to home page?

PHP page

```
 if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT password,email FROM users WHERE email = ".$email." AND password = ".$password." LIMIT 1");

}
```

index.html

```
   $('form#login').submit(function(){
      var email = $("form#login input.email").val();
      var pass = $("form#login input.pass").val();
           $.post("ajax/post_login.php", {email: email, pass: pass},
               function(data){
               alert("failed"); //if not logged in
               });
    });
```

I'm having trouble here?

Can someone help me out with jquery mobile?

I have different many `<div data-role="page">(content here)</div>` and I want to know how to access a certain page, when logged in? and if email/username fails, theres an error?

I appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, there is no problem on SO about posting specific examples.  What we strive for here is to "help people help themselves", and most often, that involves someone not being aware of a particular tool or utility that can help them with a problem.  What we try to avoid is questions like "Please write my very specific code for me", because these kinds of questions will be unhelpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by posting the login data to the server with custom AJAX and letting the server respond with a JSON object containing the data needed to take an appropriate action.

**The script looked something like this (uses jQuery):**

```
formHandling.formSubmit = function (event, form) {      
    $.post(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), function (result) {           
        var response = result,
            redirectUrl;

        //Redirect is set, we prio this.
        if (response.Redirect) {

            redirectUrl = response.Redirect;

            //Default redirect can be overridden by querystring
            if (helpers.getParameterByName("redir") !== "") {
                redirectUrl = helpers.getParameterByName("redir");
            }

            document.location.href = redirectUrl; //This will cause a "full page load", but is desired in order to clean out the "Logged out view" of the pages
        } else if (response.Result) { //If no redirect is set, display the result in the target

            var resultTargetId = form.attr("data-result-target-id");
            formHandling.displayResult(resultTargetId, response.Result); //Displays an error/success message in element with id = resultTargetId
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
};
```

**And sample JSON data returned from server side:**

```
//Failed login
{
    Redirect: null, 
    Result: {
        IsError: true,
        ErrorMessage: "Failed to login" 
    }
}

//Successful login
{
    Redirect: "http://www.example.com/someloggedinpage",    
    Result: {
        IsError: false,
        ErrorMessage: ""    
    }
}
```